# If I want to use dig/nslookup to query about machines in a VLAN, how can I find which name server to use?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, nslookup, dig

If I want to use `dig/nslookup` to query about machines in e.g., 38.102.145.0/24, how can I find the *name server* to use that could resolve machines in that VLAN?

Comment: Hi, Do you have access to the VLAN traffic ? I ask as master browser and such traffic are brodcasted, it can help locate who is the local nameserver usually

Comment: Thanks, @yagmoth555: unfortunately, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

DNS and VLANs don't have anything to do with one another.

If you want to find the authoritative name server(s) for that ip address range then perform a lookup for the name server(s) of that rDNS zone.